# console.log doesn't print the message to the firebug console?

Tags: javascript, console, firebug

I am facing this weird problem. The WebApp I'm debugging right now, is invoking the javascript console.log/console.log/error/debug/etc., the Firebug console however, doesn't print them at all.
This application uses Dojo/Dijit toolkit. Not sure if there is anything special about it

It doesn't appear to be a problem with the Browser, I tried another simple web-page with a console.debug call, and the message appears on the console as expected.

Please advise about what should I look for. I have also tried Chrome/IE.

Thanks in Advance/

Comment: Could be there is another debugging setup that's intercepting it. If you can post a link or a http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate, that would help.

Comment: I have a similar problem once in a while - console.logs on the script don't fire but if I do them manually on the console they work. Restarting the browser solves it. (Still no idea where the issue comes from - I am using Dojo as well however...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`console` is not write protected, it can be replaced with anything. You could try

```
alert(console.log.toString());
```

to find out what `console.log` really is

### Edit:

A better method would be

```
var originalConsole = console;
// now include your library
// ...
originalConsole.log(console.log);
```

In Firebug, clicking on the function takes you directly to its definition.

Comment: Awesome! This answered my question. a simple search showed me where in code the console.log was getting assigned to `code` function(){}

Answer (score 6):

did you try `window.console.log()`? Maybe you are not in window scope

Comment: yes, that solve scope issue better. Please mark as correct answer his answer

Answer (score 3):

In case like this do not forget to check if "Logging" is enabled or active at your console of browser.

Comment: My bad I had clicked on 'Errors' subtab of Console tab in firebug

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question -:
Ensure that firebug is Enabled - - > On for all Web Pages. 
Reload the application.
Then in the firebug panel - - > Console - - > All.
All the console.log messages will appear.